# Problema al validar un formulario, el elemento input no coge los nuevos estilos de clase

Tags: javascript, html, css, formularios

Hola buenas estoy aprendiendo a validar formularios y tengo un problema con las clases, en caso de que el usuario no rellene un campo de tipo text, a ese campo le he querido cambiar la clase para que el sombreado que tiene cambie del suyo por defecto (morado) a una nueva clase que pone el sombreado en color rojo. El problema se soluciona si en el css en la nueva clase creada (.campoError), le añado `!important` pero tengo entendido que es una mala práctica y que a google no le gusta demasiado eso.
Por otro lado también he probado con:

`element.className="campoError"`
`element.classList.toogle("campoError")`
Ninguno me soluciona nada, sigue manteniendo los valores por defecto y no consigo cambiar su clase. Empiezo a creer que es por algún conflicto con el css, pero no lo encuentro.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    
    var boton_datos = document.getElementById('boton_datos');
    
    boton_datos.onclick=function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        validar();
    }
}
function validar() {
    var formu = document.forms[0];
    var c_nombre= formu.nombre;
    var c_email= formu.email;
    var c_asunto = formu.asunto;
    if (c_nombre.value == ""){
        alert("ei pon un nombre");
        c_nombre.focus();
        c_nombre.classList.toggle("campoError");
        return;
    }
    
}
```

```css
.campo input{
    padding: 1rem;
    border: none;

    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px green;  
    outline: none;
    color: var(--parrafos);
}
.campoError{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px red; 
}


.campo input:focus{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px purple;
   
}
```

```html
<form action="correo.php" method="post">
                    <div class="widget">
                        <h3>Contacta conmigo<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></h3>
                        
                        
                        <div class="campo">
                            
                            <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre"autocomplete="off" >
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        </div>
                        
                        
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos" class="boton" name="envio" id="boton_datos">
                    </div>
                    
                    
                </form>
```

La idea es que el usuario al no rellenar el campo, le salte un aviso y hacerle focus al campo sin rellenar con la nueva clase que te pone el input en rojo.

¿Se os ocurre algo? Un saludo.

Comment: El error es `"Uncaught TypeError: c_nombre.classList.toogle is not a function"`. Lo cual es esperable porque deberías llamar a `toggle` y no `toogle`

Comment: Es que toogle rima con google :-)  (a mi me ha pasado varias veces y mira que lo se, pero sigo repitiendo ese error)

Comment: @PabloLozano ha sido un pequeño lapsus jaja, pero la verdad, lo he cambiado a lo que has dicho `toggle` y tampoco me lo está cogiendo :(

Comment: Tambien te sobra un `</div>` encima del `input` **submit**, o despues, como prefieras

Comment: Ponle un `!important` a esto:  `box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px red !important;` y diria que ya tendras lo que quieres

Comment: @masterguru lo del !important es lo que explico en el post, que eso sí me lo soluciona pero que es una mala práctica y por lo visto google no le gusta eso, entonces estaba buscando la alternativa. Lo del div es porque en realidad el código es mucho más gordo y lo necesito, en este post he puesto lo mismo pero más simplificado para que no sea tanto código.

Comment: A google diria que no le importa el important, y valga la redundancia :-) No lo leí, perdona, es que a veces voy de listo y me leo las cosas en diagonal :-)  Lo de la mala practica es porque cuesta más de mantener y puede solaparse facilmente con otras hojas de estilos, etc, pero si funciona y no da conflictos no le veo la pega.

Comment: @masterguru yo tengo entendido que un código cargado de importants es señal de un mal código... Lo que me parece raro es que no me funcione con lo otro. Por ejemplo className= "nueva clase", está cogiendo la nueva clase, pero no los nuevos valores, es curioso.

Comment: Hombre, si lo cargas de muchos !important quizas si que quedaria feo... pero por uno no me preocuparia demasiado... aun asi, tiene que haber otra forma, seguro.... quedate a la escucha a ver si alguien lo resuelve pues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las reglas de CSS se aplican con una jerarquía dada por lo restrictiva que sean: una regla que sea `etiqueta .clase` es más restrictiva que una que sea `.clase`.

Por tanto, la regla

```
.campo input{
  ...
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px green;  
}
```

Es más restrictiva que

```
.campoError{
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px red; 
}
```

y por tanto la segunda no se aplica si entra en conflicto con la primera.
Una solución sencilla es volver la regla que quieres aplicar más restrictiva:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    
    var boton_datos = document.getElementById('boton_datos');
    
    boton_datos.onclick=function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        validar();
    }
}
function validar() {
    var formu = document.forms[0];
    var c_nombre= formu.nombre;
    var c_email= formu.email;
    var c_asunto = formu.asunto;
    if (c_nombre.value == ""){
        alert("ei pon un nombre");
        c_nombre.focus();
        c_nombre.classList.toggle("campoError");
        return;
    }
    
}
```

```css
.campo input{
    padding: 1rem;
    border: none;

    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px green;  
    outline: none;
    color: var(--parrafos);
}
.campo input.campoError {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px red; 
}


.campo input:focus{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px purple;
   
}
```

```html
<form action="correo.php" method="post">
                    <div class="widget">
                        <h3>Contacta conmigo<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></h3>
                        
                        
                        <div class="campo">
                            
                            <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre"autocomplete="off" >
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        </div>
                        
                        
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar datos" class="boton" name="envio" id="boton_datos">
                    </div>
                    
                    
                </form>
```

Comment: Sí!!!! Funciona y comprendo el error, muchísimas gracias.